# RC2135 file not found error

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I manually added code fro a new dialog box in my .rc file and I have started getting this error.

error RC2135: file not found: 0

I don't understand this error as it is not specifying any filename.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
SG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

I had forgotten to add dialogex after the dialog id in rc file.

Answer (score 2):

It may help someone, but just got this error, and the problem was, I accidentally pasted some nonsense text at the beginning of my .rc file (I was trying to paste it somewhere else, and this window must've been active at the time).